# Sort a very large python list that is posted from a client

Tags: python, performance, sorting

I have an API endpoint that accepts a POST request with a json list in it which is huge (Size <=10^7). I want this endpoint to sort the numbers and return a json dump of the sorted list. Right now, this is how my code looks like:

```
def sorting():
    content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    ordered = numpy.sort(content, kind='mergesort')
    return json.dumps(ordered.tolist())
```

However, this is taking extremely long times. For example, for an array of size, 1 million, it takes 55 seconds. Is there a way to not necessairly load the entire json into memory and sort it but instead do it on the go then simply dump it?

Note: I also tried kind=quicksort and very similar run time.

Comment: How would that work, exactly? You need the whole list to be certain you’ve sorted it correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to optimize this though? I don't believe just loading everything into memory, sorting, then dumping is the optimum way no?

Comment: Honestly, I personally think the best option will just be to outsource it to something like aws lambda maybe or perhaps just celery will be enough for you.

Comment: It is not clear to me where in that you see any room for improvement.

Comment: It's not so big that you can't load it in memory and sort it. But what you should do is measure how long each of your steps actually are. How long does it take to receive or send this data? To parse? To do the actual sort?